# iframe containing querystring causes problems in JSF

Tags: jsf, iframe, query-string, jsf-2

I am trying to insert a Yahoo weather widget in a JSF page. The code generated by Yahoo is:

```
<!-- Yahoo! Weather Badge --><iframe allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://weather.yahoo.com/badge/?id=12753136&u=c&t=trans&l=vertical" height="255px" width="186px"></iframe><!-- Yahoo! Weather Badge -->
```

Notice that the iframe src contains a querystring. When I try to run this, I get this error:

```
Error Traced[line: 42] The reference to entity "u" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Why is it trying to interpret the querystring characters as an entity? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're apparently using XML/XHTML. You need to replace all "plain vanilla" ampersands `&` by `&amp;`.